# Successful settimeofday() randomly function locks up application

Tags: c++, multithreading, debian, ntp

I have a C++ application running on a Raspberry Pi (DietPi Distro - Jessie) and am using GPS data to update the system time at boot.  The code is simple, however, it crashes or locks up the application about 50% of the time.  No exceptions are thrown and I've tried to capture any stderr in a log file with no success.  Occasionally I see a segmentation fault, but I think this may be unrelated.

The portion of the code that clearly causes the crash is "settimeofday(&tv, NULL)".  I can comment out only this and it will run fine, but here's the segment of code that assigns timeval 'tv' and changes the system time:

```
//Convert gps_data_t* member 'time' to timeval
timeval tv;
double wholeseconds, decimalseconds, offsettime;
offsettime = gpsdata->fix.time - (5.0 * 3600.0);
decimalseconds = modf(offsettime, &wholeseconds);
tv.tv_sec = static_cast<int32_t>(wholeseconds);
tv.tv_usec = static_cast<int32_t>(decimalseconds * 1000000.0);

//Set system time - THIS IS CAUSING CRASHES, WHY?
if ( settimeofday(&tv, NULL) >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Time set successful!" << '\n';
} else {
    std::cout << "Time set failure!" << '\n';
}
```

A point I would like to make is the setting of the time is successful when the system crashes.  I have seen it unsuccessful in the case where gpsdata->fix.time is 'NaN', and it seems to handle this well and just report a failure.  My own theories of possible causes:

> This is a multi-threading program where several other threads are in a
>   sleep state (std::this_thread::sleep_for() used extensively).  Does
>   changing the system time while these threads are in a sleep state
>   interfere with the time it comes out of sleep?
>
> I know there is a time service (NTP?) in the Debian distro that
>   manages system time synchronization.  Could this be interfering?

Anyways, I've got some more experimenting to do but it seems like something somebody may recognize immediately.  All advice is appreciated.

---

A few other points, I've followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29663/how-do-i-disable-ntpd) link to remove the ntpd service and the issue still stands, ruling that cause out.  Furthermore, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427808/what-is-the-effect-of-changing-system-time-on-sleeping-threads) link that says changing the system time during a sleeping thread doesn't impact when it wakes up.  So now my two theories are shot.  Any other ideas are appreciated!

---

Because of the occasional segmentation fault that occurs, which is not clear if it's related or not to the freezing/crashing, I went ahead and updated the code to prevent the only source of undefined behavior I could identify.  So I added uniform initialization for all the variables used in the modf function and made my timeval const.  Also changed the type casts per advice below.  Behavior is still the same.

```
//Loop until first GPS lock to set system time
while ( (gpsdata == NULL) ||
        (gpsdata->fix.mode <= 1) ||
        (gpsdata->fix.time < 1) ||
        std::isnan(gpsdata->fix.time) ) {
    gpsdata = gps_rec.read();
}

//Convert gps_data_t* member 'time' to timeval
double offsettime{ gpsdata->fix.time - (5.0 * 3600.0) };    //5.0 hr offset for EST
double seconds{ 0.0 };
double microseconds{ 1000000.0 * modf(offsettime, &seconds) };
const timeval tv{ static_cast<time_t>(seconds),
                  static_cast<suseconds_t>(microseconds) };

//Set system time - THIS IS CAUSING CRASHES, WHY?
if ( settimeofday(&tv, NULL) >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Time set successful!" << '\n';
} else {
    std::cout << "Time set failure!" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: note that timeval.tv_sec is *not* necessarily of type int32_t (it may well be 64-bit to avoid a Y2038 problem).  Ideally use `static_cast<decltype(timeval::tv_sec)>(...)`, but `static_cast<time_t>(...)` would be a lot better.  (Comment, because that isn't your problem)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I actually wasn't sure what type to cast to for the timeval members.

Comment: `Occasionally I see a segmentation fault, but I think this may be unrelated.` A segmentation fault is never unrelated. If you have a segmentation fault you've had undefined behavior "somewhere" (it may have been 5 functions ago...)

Comment: The segmentation fault does not occur with the above code commented out.  Do you see any potential above for undefined behavior?